# google checkout not displaying shipping options

Tags: google-checkout

I'm using GCheckout.dll (Google Checkout v2.5.0.6 dll - http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-dotnet-sample-code/downloads/list) to implement google checkout payments in a C# application.

I have configured UPS shipping on the merchant account and intentionaly not specified any shiping options in the C#, to use the ones configured in the account. For some reason though, no shipping options are apearing. Any ideas why? I though the whole point of configuring them in the merchant account is to display those when the application doesn't send any through the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article below may help.

There are various reasons why tax or shipping options specified in the Checkout Merchant Center are ignored. For example, if you submit a cart XML that contains the shipping-methods or tax-tables tags, the Merchant Center settings will be overriden.

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/articles/Troubleshoot_Merchant_Issues.html

Comment: Thanks. My problem was using Carrier calculate (UPS) and not sending a weight for it.

Comment: The link is now dead.